# Regex for SIP and SIPS URIs

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

Sample Sip URI

```
   sip:alice@atlanta.com
   sip:alice:secretword@atlanta.com;transport=tcp
   sips:alice@atlanta.com?subject=project%20x&priority=urgent
   sip:+1-212-555-1212:1234@gateway.com;user=phone
   sips:1212@gateway.com
   sip:alice@192.0.2.4
   sip:atlanta.com;method=REGISTER?to=alice%40atlanta.com
   sip:alice;day=tuesday@atlanta.com
```

the regex I created `^(sip|sips):([^@]+)@(.+)`

What I am trying to achieve is @ is optional, if @is there something before and after @ should be there, otherwise after sip: anything can be accepted

Comment: Did my answer help/work for you? Please consider accepting if it woked for you.

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
^(sips?):([^@]+)(?:@(.+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5OJJxF/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(sips?)` - Group 1: `sip` or `sips`
- `:` - a colon
- `([^@]+)` - Group 2: 1 or more chars other than `@`
- `(?:@(.+))?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `@` - a `@` char
  - `(.+)` - Group 3: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

NOTE: if you use the pattern with `.matches()` method, `^` and `$` are redundant and can be removed from the pattern as that method requires a full string match.

Comment: Its passes underscore between @ and .com like "125.125.125@______.com:11221"

Comment: @Eugene You have different requirements, see what problem is in the question: "*What I am trying to achieve is @ is optional, if `@is` there **something before and after `@` should be there**, otherwise after sip: **anything can be accepted***". No restrictions here but `sip:` and `@` must be in the string. If you have different requirements, please ask a new question.

Comment: Wiktor you'r right. Its valid for asked question.